# Cast a Type to a class

Tags: c#, reflection, indexing

If I have a class defined like this:

```
public class className
{
    public object this[string propertyName]
    {
        get { return this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this, null); }
        set { this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(this, value, null); }
    }

    public string Foo{ get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
```

I can of course set and get the values like this:

```
className d = new className();
d["Foo"]="abcd" // set
string s = (string)f["Bar"];
```

(thanks to [Eduardo Cuomo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/717267/eduardo-cuomo) for his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp))

But what I'd really like to do is something like:

```
Type target = Type.GetType(DocumentType);

// loop through list of key-value pairs and populate the data class defined in target object Type
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> PQList in LPQReq)
{

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in PQList)
{
    // populate the member in the data class with the value from the MQ String
    target[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;                                                
    }
```

but this wouldn't compile as `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Type'`

so how could I do that?

I can use `dynamic` of course, but maybe there is a way to cast my Type to my target Class?

Comment: `target` is a class; what's the *instance* of that class on which you would like to set all these properties, though?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Well, I have more than a dozen data classes, so I create a type based on the definition given in the string `DocumentType`. This means I can populate all the classes generically without having to specify the properties and members...

Comment: Whether you get the type or not, you do not have any instance of this object. Even you manage to do this, you will get that the object is not set to a reference of an object

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: in my question, `DocumentType` would in this case reference `className`

Comment: Would defining the [indexer on an interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkyhsw31.aspx) and having all your classes that have this pattern also implement the interface be viable? Then your code would create the object (say via `Activator.CreateInstance(target)`), cast it to the interface, and then you can read/write the properties.

Comment: Have you tried `className["foo"]` because it would not work to use indexer from static context. You can manage your `target` to be from type `className`, but it WILL NOT BE an instance of `className`

Comment: @RoyalBg: so is my whole house of cards falling over? How can I instantiate my `target`? Or is that a whole new question?

Comment: You can do it via reflection. Take a look at the `Activator` class. I also thing you'd better have a generic method that recieves that instance and apllies indexer to it, if you have dozen of that classes. `public void SomeMethod(T obj) { obj["foo"] = "bar"; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with reflection. Assuming that all possible `DocumentType`s have a parameterless constructor, you can do it like this:

```
// Get the type (this comes from your example)
Type target = Type.GetType(DocumentType);
// Create an instance (that's the important part that was missing)
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(target);
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> PQList in LPQReq) {
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in PQList) {
        // This code again comes from your example,
        // except propertyName is kvp.Key and value is kvp.Value
        target.GetProperty(kvp.Key).SetValue(instance, kvp.Value, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me the missing `object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(target);` piece.. Would I be right in that without this my `target` is not instantiated?..

Comment: @Banana `target` is a [`System.Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) instance, not an instance of that type.

Comment: @OurManInBananas Right, `instance` is the object created from your `target` type.

Comment: Thank you so much, this has no doubt saved me much gnashing of teeth and screaming...

Comment: The reflection in notepad problems :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to instantiate the type in order to access the indexer, and you need to cast it to something that has an indexer.

You could define an interface:

```
public interface IIndexable_String
{
    object this[string index]
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Apply it to your classes:

```
public class someclass : IIndexable_String
```

Then instantiate the instance and access the indexer.

```
Type target = Type.GetType(DocumentType);

// Instantiate
IIndexable_String instance = (IIndexable_String)Activator.CreateInstance(target);
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> PQList in LPQReq)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in PQList)
    {
        // populate the member in the data class with the value from the MQ String
        instance[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;                                                
    }
```

Of course, if you do it like @dasblinkenlight does, you don't even need the magic getters and setters in the class, nor the interface.

Comment: `instance[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;` instead of `target`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, for now I am going to try the answer by @dasblinkenlight